# Editing posts with linkrot, preferred approaches

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, broken-link

I have come across a few examples, the most recent [can be seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8777882/revisions), where a proposed edit attempted to fix a dead link. I *improved* the edit by choosing to use archive.org's webarchive of the page. Is this the preferred method? I figure it must be better than just linking to another blog which may (and most likely) eventually disappear. Any other best practices/approaches I should know about?

*Also, here's [a related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16807/how-to-cleanup-deadlinks) talking about the possibility of having some function internal to Stack Exchange that would search for and replace dead links with cached copies (archive.org/google cache)...interesting.*

Comment: Eithet works, frankly, as long as the _original_ content is preserved.

Comment: I agree with original content being referenced with a cached page via archive.org. I somewhat disagree with replacing a broken web page with a different content page. The latter is a judgment which I feel should be left alone until we can tackle a cache policy of some sort.